# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'ManagedBean' returned null

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, propertynotfoundexception

I am new in ADF JSF please assist,
I am trying to map my Managed bean scope like request ,pageFlow and backingBean .
but getting following errors,

```
ManagedBean -- Scope =  request 
Error -- javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'ManagedBean' returned null 

ManagedBean --- scope = backingBean or pageFlow
Error --- An invalid object operation was invoked on type View Object with name EmployeeViewImpl_0
```

This is the exception:

```
javax.el.ELException: oracle.jbo.InvalidObjAccessException: JBO-25036: An invalid object operation was invoked on type View Object with name EmployeeViewImpl_0
  at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:266)
  at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
  at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java­:72)
  at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:118)
```

Comment: please mention the environment and log details..

Comment: @ Abhishek thanks  I m using JDeveloper / ADF 11.1.1.3.0, log details as bellow javax.el.ELException: oracle.jbo.InvalidObjAccessException: JBO-25036: An invalid object operation was invoked on type View Object with name EmployeeViewImpl_0
 at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:266)
 at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
 at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
 at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:118)

Comment: Is your ManagedBean declared in taskflow definition file?

Comment: @Juanmi thanks for your reply.Yes i have declared ManagedBean in adfc-config.xml, I have resolved this problem , i have mapped scope of manageBean as backingBean and declared the parameter setter/getter in implementation class which is my managedBean, now i can able to pass my parameter from one jsf page to database query and retrieve the query values  in second jsf page.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue and I have solved. My stack trace was similar and my problem was that I was invoking an action method of a Managed Bean from a task flow, but in the managed bean, this method had as return: void. And this was my mistake.

I change the type of return to String and all works fine.

I hope this help you.
Marcos.